# Domain Access force node redirect to proper domain

Tags: redirection, domain-access

Using Domain Access with Drupal 6, I am encountering an issue in the following scenario:

I set up a node published to a sub site, say:

```
subsite.com/node-x
```

If I browse to:

```
mainsite.com/node-x
```

I would like it to redirect to:

```
subsite.com/node-x
```

However, it just renders the content on the main site domain (which the search engines would pick up as duplicate content).

Any idea how I can configure the sites to redirect to the site on which the node is published? I attempted to use Global Redirect to redirect from the main site to the full url  on the sub site but Drupal told me that I was redirecting something to itself. Are web server redirects my only option?

Comment: For anyone looking for an update on this, I never ended up finding something that worked. I cobbled together my own module to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a special module for that: https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_path_rewrite.

The idea is to check the request path before the page load and to make a redirect to the proper domain if needed. Something like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function domain_path_rewrite_init() {
  if ($domain_path = _domain_path_rewrite_domain_path(current_path())) {
    global $_domain;

    if (!($_domain['domain_id'] == $domain_path['domain_id'] && request_path() == $domain_path['path'])) {
      drupal_goto($domain_path['url'], array(), 301);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I'm looking for D6, too.

Looks like D7 can be found here: https://drupal.org/node/1566058

This seems to work for D6: https://drupal.org/node/704568

Answer (score -3):

I believe [Domain 301 Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/domain_301_redirect) mixed with domain source will do what you are after.

> The Domain 301 Redirect module allows sites to 301 redirect to a
>   domain that is marked as the main domain. This means you can have all
>   subdomains and other domains pointing to the site 301 redirect to a
>   domain that you choose as the main domain. This provides great SEO
>   benefit.